# How to determine length of occupied spaces in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have an array and 
I need to check the number of elements which are not null.

For example:

```
String carlist[] =new String[50]

carlist[0] = ferrari
carlist[1] = bentley

//all other values will be null.
```

How do I find out the answer, 2, which is the number of occupied places?

Comment: You may wish to consider an alternative approach, e.g. using an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the number of non-null elements in an array:

```
int count = 0;
for(String car : carlist) {
    if(car != null) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

But if you're inserting items sequentially, you should just be able to calculate `carlist.length - (lastID + 1)`.

Comment: I think the condition should be !=. OP wants the number of NOT NULL values

Answer (score 0):

You can put int variable `count` as the index, where each time you add to the array of String `count` will increment thus giving you the number of occupied spaces.

**example:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int count = 0;
    String carlist[] = new String[50];

    carlist[count] = "ferrari";
    carlist[++count] = "bentley";
    System.out.println("occupied spaces" + (count + 1));
    System.out.println("empty spaces" + (carlist.length - (count + 1)));
}
```